# How to make a proper reactive extension on Eureka SelectableSection

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactive, swift-extensions, eureka-forms

This is my first question to the StackOverflow community so excuse me if I'm doing something wrong.

**1. What I'm trying to achieve**
Basically, I want to make a custom reactive wrapper around Eureka's `SelectableSection` class in order to observe the value of the selected row when it is changed. I'm thinking to get this data from the `onSelectSelectableRow` closure which is called every time a row is selected.

**2. What I've tried to do for that**
Actually, I've got this working but it's not a generic use of the custom wrapper, here is the example that works but only when I specify the row and its value type, for example `ListCheckRow<Int>`.

```swift
extension SelectableSection: ReactiveCompatible {}
extension Reactive where Base : SelectableSection<ListCheckRow<Int>> {
  var selectedValue: Observable<Base.SelectableRow.Cell.Value?> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
      self.base.onSelectSelectableRow = {cell, row in
        observer.onNext(row.value)
      }
      return Disposables.create {
        observer.onCompleted()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine and as I expected but when it comes to something more generic like the next code example, I get an error saying that: **"Cannot assign to property: 'base' is a 'let' constant"**

```swift
extension SelectableSection: ReactiveCompatible {}
extension Reactive where Base : SelectableSectionType {
  var selectedValue: Observable<Base.SelectableRow.Cell.Value?> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
      self.base.onSelectSelectableRow = {cell, row in // Error: Cannot assign to property: 'base' is a 'let' constant
        observer.onNext(row.value)
      }
      return Disposables.create {
        observer.onCompleted()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Not really related to question, but I will advise against using Eureka in case if you want any degree of row customisation. Last time I tried to use it I created 7 issues on their github page and write off the time spend as a loss, reimplementing the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, actually for now this is the easiest way for me, maybe later I'll think for something else.

Comment: Yeah, it was perfect for quick prototyping, I did the task (server-side forms) in 2 days. And spend a week trying to apply custom design. The issue is at the time (2 years ago) Eureka was concealing appearance related logic in private or non-virtual methods and sealed classes. Also, its code is "Swift-heavy", in a bad way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that `SelectableSectionType` is a protocol that isn't restricted to class types and `Reactive` assumes that `Base` is a class (or otherwise is not going to be modified by the observable creation.)

I think the most generic you can make this is something like:

```
extension Reactive {
    func selectedValue<Row, T>() -> Observable<T?> where Base: SelectableSection<Row>, Row: SelectableRowType, T == Row.Cell.Value  {
        Observable.create { [base] observer in
            base.onSelectSelectableRow = { cell, row in
                observer.onNext(row.value) // this is problematic. See below.
            }
            return Disposables.create {
                observer.onCompleted() // this is wrong. See below.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The biggest problem with the above though is that if you subscribe to the resulting Observable more than once or create more than one Observable using this computed property, all but the last subscription will silently fail. The simple way to fix this is to always remember to share any result but that's rather error prone.

The way to fix this would be to associate a Subject with each SelectableSection, but you can't modify the class, so what are we to do?

Here's a solution:

```
extension Reactive {
    func selectedValue<Row, T>() -> Observable<T?> where Base: SelectableSection<Row>, Row: SelectableRowType, T == Row.Cell.Value  {
        Observable.create { [base] observer in
            if let block = selectableSections.first(where: { $0.section === base }) {
                let subject = block.subject as! PublishSubject<T?>
                return Disposables.create(
                    block.disposable.retain(),
                    subject.subscribe(observer)
                )
            }
            else {
                let subject = PublishSubject<T?>()
                let block = SelectableSectionBlock(
                    section: base,
                    subject: subject,
                    disposable: RefCountDisposable(disposable: Disposables.create {
                        selectableSections.removeAll(where: { $0.section === base })
                    })
                )
                base.onSelectSelectableRow = { cell, row in
                    subject.onNext(row.value)
                }
                selectableSections.append(block)
                return Disposables.create(
                    block.disposable,
                    subject.subscribe(observer)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

private struct SelectableSectionBlock {
    let section: Section
    let subject: Any
    let disposable: RefCountDisposable
}

private var selectableSections = [SelectableSectionBlock]()
```

The `selectableSections` array stores a Subject and RefCountDisposable for each SelectableSection.

Whenever an Observable is created, or subscribed to...

- if it's the first time working with this section, it will create a Subject and RefCountDisposable assign the onSelectSelectableRow to send a next event to the subject and store the subject in the array.
- otherwise it will find the subject and disposable associated with this Section and retain the disposable.

Once it has the subject and disposable from above, it will subscribe the new observer to the subject and return a new Disposable that will remove that subscription and decrement the ref-count when the time comes.

Yes this is quite a bit more complex than the simple assignment case, but it's the right thing to do.

As for calling `onCompleted()` inside the disposable closure. By the time the closure is called, the observer has already emitted an onCompleted/onError event, or the observer has stopped listening to the observable. So this event will never be seen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a goo explanation, it's good block of code for me to study!